# What's the Semantic Web got to do with GIS?

Tags: gis-principle

A few years ago there was a lot of [discussion about the Semantic Web](http://www.w3.org/2011/gld/wiki/Geography_and_Spatial_Information).  Are any of the concepts underlying the Semantic Web coming into fruition with respect to GIS?  Or is it just another hippie dream?

> I have a dream for the Web [in which computers] become capable of
>   analyzing all the data on the Web – the content, links, and
>   transactions between people and computers. A ‘Semantic Web’, which
>   should make this possible, has yet to emerge, but when it does, the
>   day-to-day mechanisms of trade, bureaucracy and our daily lives will
>   be handled by machines talking to machines. The ‘intelligent agents’
>   people have touted for ages will finally materialize.
>   - [Tim Berners-Lee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web)

Sounds like Tim may have been [fishing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trout_Fishing_in_America) the same streams as [Richard Brautigan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Brautigan), whose poem published in 1963, [All Watched Over by Machines of Loving Grace](http://www.redhousebooks.com/galleries/freePoems/allWatchedOver.htm) has everything but the cloud:

```
I'd like to think (and
the soner the better!)
of a cybernetic meadow
where mammals and computers
live together in mutually
programming harmony
like pure water
touching clear sky.
```

Comment: You may not have been exposed to the recent documentary using the Brautigan poem as title: http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b011k45f the first episode is here, not for long I suppose: http://vimeo.com/27393748

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ordnance Survey** (Great Britain Mapping Agency) have a dedicated case study on [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/sweo/public/UseCases/OrdSurvey/) and have embraced the Semantic Web and use it to distribute linked metadata between systems.

*Ordnance Survey is Great Britain’s national mapping agency. We create and update the definitive mapping data of England, Scotland and Wales. From this we produce and market a wide range of digital information and paper maps for business, leisure, educational and administrative use. Every day, we make more than 5,000 updates to our central database: the largest vector geospatial database in the world. These revisions reflect house extensions, major new buildings and other natural and man-made changes.*

"We are publishing an Administrative Geography for Great Britain in
[RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework)"

Ordnance Survey linked data

The data for this description was obtained from the SPARQL service. This data is also available as: **[RDF/XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-rdf-syntax/)**, **[Turtle](http://www.w3.org/TeamSubmission/turtle/)** and **[JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)**.

A basic example is:
http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/.rdf

Postcode unit example
http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/doc/postcodeunit/SO164GT
http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/doc/postcodeunit/SO164GT.rdf

Comment: Removed the TALIS links as TALIS no longer provides semantic web operations.  Ref: https://www.information-age.com/talis-shuts-down-semantic-web-operations-2111803/